# Every time I log into Facebook, the SMS based 2FA code appears to get intercepted (UK)

Tags: man-in-the-middle, multi-factor, spoofing, facebook, sms

Historically, whenever I logged in I got a standard looking text from "Facebook" stating my login code.

As of this morning, when I attempt to log in, I get a fake looking text from a random phone number. The word "Face" in Facebook has weird italic characters. However, the login code WORKS. Clearly some kind of scammer is intercepting the texts, and then sending on the valid code to my phone.

I didn't have a phone number set up on my Instagram account, but low and behind if I try and add one, the 2FA code also comes from a random number with the "Insta" part of Instagram also in weird italics. I'd also note that the codes come through slower than normal - up to a minute later than you would expect, specifically for the Instagram codes.

I've obviously stopped using the codes now (after testing to ensure they're valid). I've also deleted my phone number from my Facebook account and it can no longer be used to sign into Facebook.

I've switched to using an authenticator app for sign in.

However, I'd still like to understand what is going on. I red an article about roaming man-in-the-middle attacks, but it indicated that a simple turning off of the phone and turning on again should solve the issues. Doing so has NOT stopped this from happening (I can confirm it's still happening as if I try to add a phone number to my Instagram account, I get a sent a code from a random phone number).

A quick Google of the phone numbers suggests scams but no clarity on what is going on. A photo of the text messages can be found [here](https://ibb.co/rGVRNXW) and [here](https://ibb.co/swT8kkw).

I am naturally worried that my texts are all being intercepted by a scammer.

- Any idea what is going on?
- Should I speak to my phone provider (Vodafone)?
- Should I take any other actions?

Thank you in advance